# Doctrine inserting on POST_WRITE event with Symfony 5 and APIplatform

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I want to add a new UserTeam(which get a team, a user and a role) each time a User create a Team. I created an event subscriber TeamFirstUserAdminSubscriber.php but it doesn't work and I have no error message.

here is my database model:
[image]

and here is the file TeamFirstUserAdminSubscriber.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Events;


use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use App\Entity\Team;
use App\Entity\UserTeam;
use App\Repository\RoleUserTeamRepository;
use App\Repository\TeamRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class TeamFirstUserAdminSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface

{
private $security;
private $repository;
private $repositoryT;
private $manager;

public function __construct(Security $security, RoleUserTeamRepository $repository, TeamRepository $repositoryT, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
{
    $this->security = $security;
    $this->repository = $repository;
    $this->repositoryT = $repositoryT;
    $this->manager = $manager;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return[
        KernelEvents::VIEW => ['setInstanceUserTeam', EventPriorities::POST_WRITE],
    ];
}

public function setInstanceUserTeam(ViewEvent $event)
{
    $team = $event->getControllerResult();
    $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

    if($team instanceof Team && $method === 'POST')
    {
        //get the user connected
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        //get the last team created
        $lastTeam = $this->repositoryT->findLastTeamCreated();

        //get the admin role (NOT the symfony one)
        $admin = $this->repository->findOneByRoleAdmin('Admin');

        //should create a new UserTeam instance with the User, the Team and the RoleUserTeam wanted
        $userTeam = new UserTeam();
        $userTeam->setUser($user);
        $userTeam->setTeam($lastTeam);
        $userTeam->setRoleUserTeam($admin);

        $manager = $this->manager;
        $manager->persist($userTeam);
        $manager->flush();


    }

}
```

The new UserTeam is not created in the databse when I try it out with postman, but the Team is well created.
I think I am missing something but I don't know what.
Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your full code(controller, forms etc), but you can achieve this without an event listener. As you already know, what team to be assigned for a user, why don't you assign that on the entity when creating the user object. For example if you using form in the controller

```
public function addAdminUser(Request $request, RoleUserTeamRepository $repository, TeamRepository $repositoryT, EntityManagerInterface $manager) 
{ 
$user = new User(); 
$form = $this->createForm(UserForm::class, $user);     
$form->handleRequest($form);          
if ($form->isSubmitted && $form->isValid()) {         
  //get the last team created         
  $lastTeam = $this->repositoryT->findLastTeamCreated();         
  //get the admin role (NOT the symfony one) 
  $admin = $this->repository->findOneByRoleAdmin('Admin');          
  //should create a new UserTeam instance with the User, the Team and the 
  RoleUserTeam wanted         

  $userTeam = new UserTeam();         
  $userTeam->setUser($user);         
  $userTeam->setTeam($lastTeam);         
  $userTeam->setRoleUserTeam($admin);         
  $user->setUserTeam($userTeam);          
  //persist the user         
  $manager->persist($user);         
  $manager->flush();     
 }     
}
```

If you want to use events I would suggest use Doctrine events. You can use **prePersist** event on user entity to achieve same result. [Doctrine Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have no controller and no forms because I am building only an API with API Platform and building my front with ReactJS.

Comment: Alright, did you try PRE_WRITE event. Also check the priority of the event. You may need to register the subscriber manually in services.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, I needed a cascade persist in my entities. Here, if it can hepl some people :
I had this in the Team entity

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->id = Team::class;
    $this->userTeams = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function userTeam()
{
    $newUserTeam = new UserTeam();
    $newUserTeam->setTeam($this);
    $this->userTeams->add($newUserTeam);
}
```

UserTeam entity, I had to add cascade={"persist"} in the relation ManyToOne:

```
class UserTeam
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Team::class, inversedBy="userTeams", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Groups({"users_read", "userTeam_read"})
 */
private $team;
```

And the TeamByUserSubscriber that I modified :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Events;

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use App\Entity\Team;
use App\Entity\UserTeam;
use App\Repository\RoleUserTeamRepository;
use App\Repository\TeamRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class TeamByUserSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
private $security;
private $repository;
private $entityManager;

public function __construct(Security $security, RoleUserTeamRepository $repository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->security = $security;
    $this->repository = $repository;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return[
        KernelEvents::VIEW => ['setUserForTeam', EventPriorities::PRE_VALIDATE],
    ];
}

public function setUserForTeam(ViewEvent $event)
{
    $team = $event->getControllerResult();
    $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

    if($team instanceof Team && $method === 'POST')
    {
        //get the connected User
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        //put the current User to the team we are creating (as the creator of the team)
        $team->setUser($user);

        //get the Admin role from the RoleUserTeam entity
        $admin = $this->repository->findOneByRoleAdmin('Admin');

        //create a new instance of UserTeam with the connected User, the Team we are creating and the role
        $userTeam = new UserTeam();
        $userTeam->setUser($user);
        $userTeam->setTeam($team);
        $userTeam->setRoleUserTeam($admin);
        $manager = $this->entityManager;
        $manager->persist($userTeam);
        $manager->flush();
    }


}
```